# MySql Add Extra Column With Case Statement From Another Table To Select Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables in total **Class**, **Subject** and **ClassSubject** where **Class** has two column *id* and *class_name*, **Subject** has two column *id* and *subject_name* and **ClassSubject** has three column *id*, *class_id* and *subject_id*.

Let's assume I have two class - *One* and *Two* in **Class** table and I have three subject *Language*, *History* and *Math* in **Subject** table.

Now for every class in **Class** table I want a list of all the subjects available in the **Subject** table with an extra column named ***is_subject*** which will either be 0 or 1 depending on if a row exists in **ClassSubject** table matching with a particular class id and every subject id.

Class Table

[image]

Subject Table

[image]

For any class id input, the result table should be like this depending whether a row exists in **ClassSubject** table.

Please note, here in the result table, *id* is the subject id, not the **Class** id nor the **ClassSubject** id

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `cross join` and `left join` as follows:

```
select c.id, c.class_name, s.subject_name, 
       case when cs.class_id is null then 0 else 1 end as is_subject
 from class c cross join subjects s
 left join classSubject cs on c.id = cs.class_id and s.id = cs.subject_id
```

**-- update**

```
select s.subject_id, s.subject_name, 
       case when cs.id is null then 0 else 1 end as is_subject
 from subjects s
 left join classSubject cs on s.id = cs.subject_id
```

Comment: I have slightly modified your query like this :-> SELECT
    s.id,
    s.subject_name,
    CASE WHEN (cs.class_id = 2 AND cs.subject_id = s.id) THEN 1 ELSE 0
END AS is_subject
FROM
    Class c
CROSS JOIN Subject s LEFT JOIN ClassSubject cs ON
    c.id = cs.class_id AND s.id = cs.subject_id. But it is giving repetitive subject rows

Comment: What is the structure of the classsubject and which one is your expected output?

Comment: ClassSubject has three columns id, `class_id` and `subject_id` where id is the primary key, _class_id_ is the foreign key from Class table and _subject_id_ is the foreign key from Subject table

Comment: You can considee qccepting this answer, if it helped you.

Comment: I did :) Just edit your updated query like this SELECT
    s.id,
    s.subject_name,
    CASE WHEN (cs.class_id = 2 AND cs.subject_id = s.id) THEN 1 ELSE 0
END AS is_subject
FROM
    Subject s LEFT JOIN ClassSubject cs ON
    cs.class_id = 2 AND s.id = cs.subject_id. You are comparing cs.class_id with NULL but I need to compare it with a particular class id and also don't forget to comapre cs.cubject_id as well